# Most barebones example of parent/child process in windows on code::blocks (C++)

Tags: c++, windows

1) I'm looking for a very barebones example of two functions (Parent, Child) respectively that would create a child process, then connect the child to the parent (where the parent can access the variables in the child process). Please keep the example as simple as possible as I am pretty sure windows code is purposefully designed to be as complicated and confusing as possible.

2) Alternatively, I am also willing to consider alternates to the WINAPI calls for creating parent/child processes (so long as it's compatible with windows).

The compiler is code::blocks, OS is Vista. Compatibility with other OS is greatly preferred, if at all possible (I know WINAPI isn't, but it's the only method I am aware of). It would be really nice if the functions had similarities to the unix functions (fork, for example).

3) For a harder alternative, how could I suspend a function in such a way I can do other things (then return back to it)? The function is already defined and can't be altered.

**Updated:**

Context:
In a sense, there's a graphical front end (parent) and a function that creates physical [.png] images (child). The problem is, the physical image rendering is a blocking process, and I want a graphical loading screen during the time it runs (creating someimage.png loading bar sorta thing). There's only two ways to do that - parent-child or a interrupt call.

The child can run the function until completion where the parent just reads an updated variable to display (from the child), or the process just temporarily pauses the functions, draws the loading image to the screen, then re-resumes.

Comment: It's **great** that you know what you want.  However, you're probably going to find that you need to give a little to get a little.  People don't generally respond well to *write this for me* type questions.

Comment: Well, I had tried to research it, but MSDN have a very complicated example, and I am not part of the copy-paste crowd. I need to dissect how it works (which the complicated version I can't do), then I will re-build it. Hence 'barebones' - I only need the basic concepts.

Comment: Additionally, I'm asking for the example because, that is all I need. There is no way to paraphrase it - and I am not sure how I would do that?

Comment: @SightS2: *If* Damon's response hasn't answered you're question, then it might help if you gave some context for what you're trying to achieve, some kind of example of what you see the processes doing so that the relationship can be understood.

Comment: @forsvarir The context would be creating a child where a single function inside the child (which is a single thread process that would otherwise cause the main program to block) would execute, periodically modifying a class (OpSystem) during the execution of the code, which parent would theoretically read, then modify the graphical display to render.

Comment: You want multiple threads. Whenever you would have used fork() on Linux/Unix, you should consider multi-threading on Windows.

Comment: @unapersson Where would I best learn about multi-threading and examples? This sounds probably like what I need.

Comment: @SightS2 A good question - you might start by looking at this pthreads tutorial - https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads. pthreads is portable - there are implementations for both Windows and Linux. For something Win32 specific, you could pick up a 2nd hand copy of this book http://www.amazon.com/Multithreading-Applications-Win32-Complete-Threads/dp/0201442345 - it's not brilliant, but its not too bad either.

Comment: @unapersson This answer is good enough that it deserves to be stand alone. Not only is it portable, it's open source, it's simplified and it's precisely what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really asking a question, but let's take this for one :-)

<strike>Basically you want a mini debugger.</strike> This is no longer true after clarifying what's really needed, but I'll leave the snippet in place, you never know who might be interested anyway.

The most barebone code for a mini-debugger looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO si = STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if(CreateProcess("child.exe", 0, 0, 0, 0, DEBUG_PROCESS, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    else
    { // maybe print some error, or don't
        return -1;
    }

    DEBUG_EVENT e;

    while (WaitForDebugEvent(&e, INFINITE))
    {
        handle_debug_event(e); // in here goes your handling
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will notify you automatically when DLLs are loaded/unloaded and when threads are created and die, and when unhandled exceptions or breakpoints are encountered. It also gives the parent process the necessary privilegues to read and write the child's process memory, modify its thread context, and set breakpoints.

Refer to the `DEBUG_EVENT` documentation on MSDN and do whatever you like inside your `handle_debug_event` function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the process occurring (forgive my naivety) - is it calling an .exe? I was hoping that, perhaps it could spawn an offshoot from the main process itself (similar to unix in that the offshoot is a duplicate of the parent)? Does this mean windows operates differently to unix?

Comment: @SightS2 are you *sure* you're looking for a process, not a thread? And yes, UNIX and windows do have different process models (there's no fork in windows)

Comment: Simulating fork+execve under Windows is non-trivial. The way the native Windows API works, you spawn a separate process directly rather than forking and replacing your own image with a different one. There is no notion of forking. To implement something like fork, you have to go a long long way (see the Cygwin documentation if you're interested), which is very cumbersome.

Comment: @Damon: +1 for innovative interpretation, it never would have occured to me that 'debug the process' was an approach.... I'd have assumed the question was more about interprocess communication...

Comment: @forsvarir: "access the variables in the child process" and "interrupt a function that cannot be altered" suggested to me that this was what SightS2 wants. But yeah, I may be wrong and it may be IPC. As Sarek said in The Voyage Home: "It is difficult to answer, when one does not understand the question." :-)

Comment: Apologies if the question is ambiguous. In a sense, there's a graphical front end (parent) and a function that creates physical [.png] images (child). The problem is, the physical image rendering is a blocking process, and I want a graphical loading screen during the time it runs. There's only two ways to do that - parent-child or a interrupt call. Either one will resolve the issue (but like XOR, not both and not neither).

Comment: So I understand that you really only just need a function within the same program that runs independently of the main program which shows some GUI to keep the user happy. The parameters that are necessary to render are defined once before that function starts, and you want to check when the rendering is finished. There is no more complicated interaction in between. If that's it, you will not need more than `CreateThread` and `WaitForSingleObject` functions (or `_beginthread` if your function uses the CRT). I can put up another code snippet for that, if this is now exactly what you want.

Comment: On the other hand, if what you need is something like "render thread changes what it is doing in reaction to the user pressing some buttons in the main thread", then you will need a much more complicated construct with proper inter-thread communication/synchronisation. Also, if "function" really means "separate program", it is of course possible to spawn another program and wait on its termination while doing other things. If _that_ is exactly what you want, I can write a snippet for that as well.